# Chrome launched by playwright performs wrong floating point math

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, floating-point, playwright

Chrome launched by playwright performs wrong floating point math.

I ran the following code on chrome developer console

```
  const f = new Float32Array(1)
  const u8 = new Uint8Array(f.buffer)
  f[0] = Infinity
  f[0] = f[0] - f[0]
  console.log(u8[3])
```

In the chrome app launched by playwright, I ran the above code on developer console to get a result of 255. However, the same floating point math on the same version of chrome launched manually by me outputs the result 127 on console. Why is there a discrepancy? Very curious what is causing this.

Comment: What do you mean by "chrome app" ? Are you doing math calculations in chrome console or are you talking about your application which you launched in chrome from playwright?

Comment: Doing the math calculations in chrome consoles. I listed results of this calculation on chrome instances launched manually and by playwright

Comment: That is not floating-point math. Examining `u8[3]` shows a byte of the encoding of a NaN (the result of ∞−∞), not any arithmetic done with numbers. JavaScript does not distinguish NaNs (although implementations may do so), and implementations may use NaN encodings with the sign bit set (which would produce a 255 high byte) or clear (which would produce a 127 high byte) and/or with various low bits set or clear.